# How To Call Query Into Script Section

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-query-builder

I have query to call data from database and how to I call the query into script section in blade.php ?

dashboard.controller :

```
 $list_state = DB::table('ref_state')
        ->where('status_state', 1)
        ->get();

foreach ($list_state as $list_state) {
        $total_people = DB::table('tbl_people')
            ->join('tbl_people_flood', 'tbl_people.id_people', '=', 'tbl_people_flood.id_people')
            ->where('tbl_people_flood.id_people', 1)
            ->where('status_people', 1)
            ->where('id_state', $list_state->id_state)
            ->count();
        $people[] = $total_people;
    }

return view('dashboard.administrator', [
        'list_state' => $list_state, 'people' => $people, 
    ]);
```

and the data show $list_state = ["Tokyo", "Helsinki", "London"] and $people = [1000, 6522, 700]

dashboard.blade.php :

```
@section('scripts')
<script>
am4core.ready(function() {

    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

    chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();

    var data = [{
        "city": "TOKYO",
        "income": 483,
        "expenses": 700
    }, {
        "city": "HELSINKI",
        "income": 1357,
        "expenses": 1000
    }];

    var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
    categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "city";
    categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

    var columnSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    columnSeries.dataFields.valueY = "income";
    columnSeries.dataFields.categoryX = "city";
 }); // end am4core.ready()

</script>
```

I want call the query into data variable and city as $list_state and income as $people..
thank you

Comment: Please try to explain your question more clearly.

Comment: If in html section, i can call the query using @foreach($list_state as $list_state) {
{{$list_state}}
}

But, in script section how can i call $list_state ?